# Combine JSON Field and add values using jq

Tags: json, string, sorting, jq

I have to aggregate a few JSON results from a site. Because the site has a query concurrency limit and the queries timeout, the time frame for the queries have to be divided. So I am left with a JSON as follows:

```
{
      "results": [
          [
              {
                  "field": "AccountId",
                  "value": "11352"
              },
              {
                  "field": "number_of_requests",
                  "value": "241398"
              }
          ],
          [
              {
                  "field": "AccountId",
                  "value": "74923"
              },
              {
                  "field": "number_of_requests",
                  "value": "238566"
              }
          ]
          ],
"statistics": {
          "recordsMatched": 502870.0,
          "recordsScanned": 165908292.0,
          "bytesScanned": 744173091162.0
      },
      "status": "Complete"
}
{
      "results": [
          [
              {
                  "field": "AccountId",
                  "value": "11352"
              },
              {
                  "field": "number_of_requests",
                  "value": "185096"
              }
           ]
          ],
"statistics": {
          "recordsMatched": 502870.0,
          "recordsScanned": 165908292.0,
          "bytesScanned": 744173091162.0
      },
      "status": "Complete"
  }
```

I need to aggregate the results, match the values to the number of requests and print out the result in descending Order.

Desired Output:

```
AccountID : Number of Requests
11352 : 426494
74923 : 238566
```

Current Output:

```
AccountID : Number of Requests
11352 : 241398
11352 : 185096
74923 : 238566
```

The jq query I am running currently takes the file name as ResultDir:

```
list=$(jq -S '.results[] | map( { (.field) : .value} ) | add ' $ResultsDir | 
  jq -s -c 'sort_by(.number_of_requests|tonumber) | reverse[] ' |
  jq -r '"\(.AccountId) : \(.number_of_requests)"')
```

How do I combine the results of the same accounts before printing it out? The results also need to be in descending order of number of requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When possible, it's generally advisable to minimize the number of calls to jq. In this case, it's easy enough to achieve the desired output with just one call to jq.

Assuming the input is a valid stream of JSON objects along the lines shown in the Q, the following produces the desired output:

```
jq -nr '
  [inputs | .results[] | map( { (.field) : .value} ) | add] 
  | group_by(.AccountId)
  | map([.[0].AccountId, (map(.number_of_requests|tonumber) | add)])
  | sort_by(.[1]) | reverse
  | .[]
  | join(" : ")
'
```

Comment: jq: error (at results-1587413190/query-results-aggregate:6830): string (" : ") and number (478) cannot be added

I get the following error.... Ignore 'results-1587413190/query-results-aggregate' as they are the file names. I am guessing this might be because some of the account IDs might be alphabets?

Comment: The result also needs to be sorted in Descending order.

Comment: 1. Please see update regarding the "descending order" requirement. 2. If your jq has `inputs`, then the join should work.  When using jq 1.4 or earlier, you would have to convert the numbers back to strings, or use "string interpolation".